# How to set a user's query quota in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are getting the following error message in BigQuery:

> Custom quota exceeded: Your usage exceeded the custom quota for
>   QueryUsagePer**User**PerDay, which is set by your administrator. For more
>   information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/cost-controls
>   (error code: quotaExceeded)

We have a custom cost control at the project level, but we just doubled this quota and it should be sufficient. And judging by the error message, the limit is exceeded on the **user** level.

Does anyone know, where exactly to modify the user limit? I've been looking in IAM & admin --> Quotas, with no luck.

Br, Torben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is at the Quotas [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas), after having selected **BigQuery API** from the *Service* menu, and the **Metric** is *Query usage per day per user*. See the screenshot:

[image: BigQuery quota]

After that, select the quota, click on *Edit Quotas* and submit a new a value.

Comment: Ahh, got it. I missed the "metric" part. Thank you so much! 

I guess Google could be more clear in their documentation that you have to pick the metric as well.